What will happen to the process attempting to go to sleep.when an interrupt occur?
chapter- 6, desin of unix operating system book (question-16).
Suppose a process attempts to go to sleep on event A but has not yet executed the code in the sleep algorithm to block interrupts; suppose an interrupt occurs before the process raises the processor execution level in sleep , and the interrupt handler attempts to awaken all processes asleep on event A.

What will happen to the process attempting to go to sleep?
2.Is this a dangerous situation? If so, how can the kernel avoid it?

algorithm sleep
input: (1) sleep address
(2) priority
output: 1 if process awakened as a result of a signal that
process catches,longjump algorithm if process awakened
as a result of a signal that it does not catch,
0 otherwise;
{
raise processor execution level to block all interrupts;
set process state to sleep;
put process on sleep hash queue, based on sleep address;
save sleep address in process table slot;
set process priority level to input priority;
if (process sleep is NOT interruptiblet
{
    do context switch;
    /* process resumes execution here when it wakes up */
    reset processor priority level to allow interrupts as when
       process went to sleep;
    return (O) ;
}
/* here, process sleep is interruptible by signals */
if (no signal pending against process)
{
    do context switch;
    /* process resumes execution here when it wakes up */
    if (no signal pending against process)
    {
        reset processor priority level to what it was when
        process went to sleep;
        return (O) ;
     }
}
remove process from sleep hash queue, if still there;

reset processor priority level to what it was when process went 
to sleep;
if (process sleep priority set to catch signals)
   return ( l );
do longjmp algorithm;
}

I cant able to find how kernel avoid.because the sleep algorithm in design unix operating system book .the algo block the intrrupt at the beginning.

Please, add to your question post the relevant code from the book. On Stack Overflow we expect the question post to contain all information which is needed to answer it.

Algorithm from book was added. Thankyou

@Tsyvarev can you help me on this question

I am not very familiar with Unix kernel design. It seems that before the line "set process state to sleep" a process should check the state of the object, responsible for the event A. If that state allows execution, then interrupts should be allowed with no sleeping being performed.
